# Rails4: ActiveRecord...CollectionProxy: NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a strange errors in rails4 that prevent me from chaining 'collect' on has_many associations.

i have `self has_many > folders` 
 
then `folder has_many > share_links` 
 
and `share_link has_many > devices`

this works as intended:

```
self.folders.first.share_links.first.devices
```

and this does not works:

```
self.folders
  .collect { |folder| folder.share_links }
  .collect { |share_link| share_link.devices }
  .uniq.count
```

with error:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `devices' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_ShaShareLink:0x007ff3b5f0dbf0>>
```

its seems that collect does not works as I think it does ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`folder.share_links` return an array. so the result of `self.folders.collect { |folder| folder.share_links }` is a two dimensional array. You have to convert it into a single dimentional array using `flatten`

```
self.folders
  .collect { |folder| folder.share_links }.flatten
  .collect { |share_link| share_link.devices }.flatten
  .uniq.count
```

SQL

```
 Model
  .joins(:folders)
  .joins("share_links on share_links.folder_id = folders.id")
  .joins("devices on devices.share_links_id = share_links.id")
  .count("distinct('<id>')")
```

Comment: thanks, "second" question: do you know how to express this query in ActiveRecord that collapse all that in one request? Am i forced to write it in full sql ?

Comment: I have given you the skeleton for how to do it in single query. Keep in mind that the joins by default are `inner joins`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But it's what I though: I am forced to expose db implementation such as tables and columns names :(